# Custom Back Button Animation

Tags: android

The default animation when the `Back` button is pressed is a slide from left to right. I'd like to replace that with a custom animation. I'm currently thinking that some combination of `onBackPressed()` and `overridePendingTransition` will do the trick, but I haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Include some sample code, otherwise we have no idea what you may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use finish() because the data stored by the Views will be erased

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
}
```

Comment: Take note of the super, it needs to be AFTER it, otherwise no effect.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins    If you are telling that `overridepending..`   should be after  the `super` , Then yes. It should be  after  any finishing calls . the super basically calls a `finish` .  so the `overrride` should be after `finish` or  the `super` in this case .

Comment: Now, is there a way to do this EXCEPT on the last back button press which would quit your app? i.e. is there a way to check the back stack and see if your app is still on it?

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins that is incorrect. The overridePendingTransition always goes LAST. When calling an intent overridePendingTransition goes last and even in the above example the overridePendingTransition goes last. The effect does work. I wanted to clear this up for anyone who may have gotten the wrong information from Chris' comment

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. I wasn't finshing the current activity. The following code does the trick.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  [This Activity].this.finish();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Comment: super.onBackPressed() automatically calls finish. Use that instead of calling finish manually..

Answer (score 1):

if you want no animation

follow the code in `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
}
```

Reference : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `onBackPressed()` since it's a hack when we use Fragments and we need to handle the stack, for instance. I proposed a more elegant solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43725255/689723