# Android Activity transition

Tags: android, transition

I am giving a transition to activity B which will be called when some button on Activity A is clicked. After clicking button Activity B is appear from Right to Left. Now I want transition Left to Right on Activity B when back button is clicked. anyone knows how to do this. I am calling onBackPressed() when I want to go to Activity A.

This is Activity A

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBtnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go_next);

        mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class));
            }
        });


    }`
```

This is Activity B

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        mBtnGoBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go_back);

        mBtnGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide, R.anim.left_slide);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_slide, R.anim.right_slide);
    }
```

`

This is my Left side
`<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>`

This is my right side
`<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Back Button Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293765/custom-back-button-animation)

Comment: Sorry friend this is not working my Activity B is also transit from Right to Left

Comment: Can you post your code which shows you going from activity A to activity B... Also your onBack code. and your XML transition files please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new folder right click on res folder create new folder name it anim. And you can put your animation xmls in it.

Use this xml in res/anim/

This is for left to right animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

This is for right to left animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

In your coding use intent like for left to right:

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,
                   R.anim.animation_leave);
In your coding use intent like for right to left

this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_leave,
                               R.anim.animation_enter);
```

Comment: sorry bro this code I have in my XML file . not work

Comment: you have to do create xml like this
 res/anim/left_to_right.xml and put left to right animation.
 res/anim/right_to_left.xml and put right to left animation.

this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right,
                   R.anim.right_to_left);

Comment: I have create same XML like this.

Comment: Add this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left); below your startActivity();